# Trigger an onPress Function from anonther component

Tags: react-native

I want to trigger an onPress function from the search icon in the navbar.
This is the search component:

```
function SearchIcon(props) {
  const theme = useSelector(state => state.themer.theme);
  return (
    <Icon.Button
      name="search"
      size={22}
      color={theme.icons}
      backgroundColor={theme.top_tab}
      onPress={() => {}}
    />
  );
}

export default SearchIcon;
```

The search component is being called in the specific stack, where it's needed.

```
<Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={({navigation, route}) => ({
          ...,
          headerRight: props => (
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <SearchIcon  />
              <CartIcon navigation={navigation} />
            </View>
          ),
        })}
      />
```

On the home screen, I have an `isSeacrhing` constant that should change value from false to true and vice versa.

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    isSearching: false,
    search: '',
...
  });

  // TRIGGERED BY SEARCH ICON IN NAV BAR
  const toggleSearch = () => setData({...data, isSearching: !isSearching});

{data.isSearching == false ? (
          <ScrollView
            ...
          </ScrollView>
        ) : (
          <View>
            <TextInput
              style={[styles.textInput, [{color: theme.text, ...FONTS.body4}]]}
              value={data.search}
              placeholder="Search..."
              placeholderTextColor={theme.text}
              onChangeText={()=>{}}
            />
          </View>
        )}
```

Is it possible to trigger the `onPress` function or is there another way I can make it work? The search icon is on two screen, does calling the same function make the `TextInput` appear on both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you use `<SearchIcon />` just add a prop in that like this

```
<SearchIcon onPress={() => { // Do Something }} />
```

Then in your `SearchIcon`

```
function SearchIcon(props) {
  const theme = useSelector(state => state.themer.theme);
  return (
    <Icon.Button
      name="search"
      size={22}
      color={theme.icons}
      backgroundColor={theme.top_tab}
      onPress={props.onPress} // Access it here like this
    />
  );
}

export default SearchIcon;
```

Comment: I assume this solution would work if `<SearchIcon/>` was called inside the displayed screen, but it's called on the <Stack.Screen/>. I don't see how I can pass `toggleSearch` into the `onPress` function.

Comment: sorry, I didn't know how to apply your solution until I found the `useLayoutEffect` hook, and using `navigation.setOptions` from react-navigation. Thanks for the help.